# Repeat for i in list - n number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

After some confusion (probably if not definitely caused by a bad question asking on my part) I am trying to work how to achieve a code to perform the following operation, but n number of times:

```
def 1_level:
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            mylist.append(i)

def 2_levels:
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                mylist.append(k)

def 3_levels:
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                for l in k:
                    mylist.append(l)

def 4_levels:
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                for l in k:
                    for m in l:
                        mylist.apend(m)

def 5_levels:
    for i in list:
        for j in i:
            for k in j:
                for l in k:
                    for m in l:
                        for n in m:
                            mylist.append(n)
```

My thoughts are as below :

```
def prunelist(n,mylist):
    if n > 0:                          # if n has not been reached
        for i in mylist:
            templist = []              #create blank list for appended items
            for j in i:
                templist.append(j)     #append items one branch down
            mylist = templist          #overwrite original list 
            n -= 1                     #reduce n by 1 
            prunelist(n,mylist)        #perform operation again (assuming n >0)

    else:
        return mylist              #when n is exhausted, output list

outputlist = prunelist(n,mylist)       #perform operation
```

(For a more rambling explanation please see edit!!!)

Cheers

J-P

Comment: Can you give input and output examples?

Comment: Please share your sample input and required output

Comment: @poke i don't think that this is what is asked here.

Comment: @poke I think the OP wants to remove `n` nestings from a regular highly nested list, if that makes sense

Comment: Did the duplicate found by poke match your expectations (it flattens an arbitrary nested list); you can adjust some of the algorithms there to keep track of nesting level if not.

Comment: In other words, do you need to flatten the list to a specified depth (the `n` arg in your `prunelist` function), or are you happy to not have to specify the depth and get a totally flattened list as the output?

Comment: Since the example input in your image differs from the one you gave as a full Python list, could you provide actual example results for that list you gave in Python?

Comment: @poke - The duplicate question provided doesn't match what I'm going for.

Comment: @poke - sorry hit enter, then had a bit of lighbulb moment, that I've totally asked the question wrong. Then was timed out to edit comment above

Question has been heavily (entirely) rewrittten, hope this help clear things up

Comment: @Jup Yeah, that clears everything up. Thanks for the edit – reopened the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with your `prunelist` function, there are just a few issues:

- You cannot overwrite a passed list by simply doing `mylist = templist`. This does modify the `mylist` variable but not the original variable. You could replace the contents of the original list here, but a better way would be to just return the new list (i.e. `templist`). This would also fit well with the other recursion case where you return the unmodified `mylist`.
- In every iteration through `mylist`, you throw away the result from the previous iteration. Move the `templist = []` initialization outside of the loop, and the `return prunelist(n, templist)` as well

If you do that, your function already works:

```
def prunelist(n, mylist):
    if n > 0:
        templist = []
        for i in mylist:
            for j in i:
                templist.append(j)
        return prunelist(n - 1, templist)
    else:
        return mylist
```

Comment: As mentioned I will have to check this tomorrow, but at first glance, this looks excellent. I have great faith. 

Cheers for the explanation of things too, much appreciated.

Comment: Works perfectly! 

I do have one question though ... When templist is passed to the prunelist function. Is this then assigned the name 'mylist' (by virtue of that beng defined in the definition of prunelist (i.e. def prunelist(n, mylist)?

Comment: Yes, for the execution scope of that other function call, `mylist` then has the value of the outer `templist`. Those scopes will not interfere with each other though.